# Handling single and multi node deployments on Linux

Tags: linux, installation, rpm

Requirement is to create a Linux based installer that can ssh into other systems, deploy and run rpms on them.
what's the best way to accomplish this without using user visible scripts like shell or python etc. I would like to avoid configuration management tools like Ansible, Chef and puppet also.

If I try to create an rpm to deploy and install another rpm package, I am getting ".rpm.lock" errors.

Comment: "I would like to avoid configuration management tools like Ansible, Chef and puppet also." — Writing your own configuration management tool from scratch isn't going to avoid using a tool like that, it just means you're doing more work and using a tool that nobody else has any experience with.

Answer (score 0):

You enumerated the best way already. And you said you want to avoid it. Good. Then the only remaining thing is to invent your own version of Ansible and use that.

I, personally, would use Ansible for that and save myself few years of coding.

Comment: Well, if it's in-house deployment, that config mgmt tool can help. But, I need to ship the software to another customer and they performs the installation.

Tools like flexera InstallAnywhere can help. But, I am looking for alternatives.